# How to avoid RegExp remove `u` in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs, next.js

Can See This Demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-aryabhata-9bbf6

`u` should exists in `/lol/iu.flags` but it not

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

```js
import Link from "next/link";
export default () => {
    console.log("should has u", /lol/iu.flags);

    return (
        <div>
            Hello World.{" "}
            <Link href="/about">
                <a>About</a>
            </Link>
            <div>
                /lol/iu should has <b>u</b>, but got{" "}
                <font color={"red"}>{/lol/iu.flags}</font>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Side note: do not use `<font />`, it is not 1999.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is.

Comment: @epascarello do u see the demo url??? see it, u will see when print `/lol/iu.flags` , `u` is not exists, and this just a showcase, didn't need care about `<font>`

Comment: `const re = /lol/iu; console.log(re.flags)` Weird it works in console.

Comment: @epascarello my title already say in `next.js`

Comment: this have the same behaviour on your local machine or just on sandbox?

Comment: @Nico both happen

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't know why, but using the RegExp constructor seems to work, while a regular expression literal does not register the `u` flag unless `y` is also present. I can't think of any obvious reason that this would occur, as far as I was aware there was no functional difference between literals/the constructor apart from having to escape. Maybe someone else can shed some light on it, but this works:

```
<font color={"red"}>{new RegExp("/lol/", "iu").flags}</font>
```

Comment: thx, that a good point, and i found why, babel auto convert normal regexp to non unicode flags version

Comment: Never dealt with that before, but that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

i found https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex

when add this into `.babelrc`

```
["@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex", { "useUnicodeFlag": true }]
```

now it work as expected